# Why does widget draws across columns of a Row widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

This web app uses a `Row()` widget to separate the screen into a left drawing area and a right inspector area.

```
  Row(children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: DragTarget(
                builder: (context, List<int> candidateData, rejectedData) {
                  return Center(
                      child: CustomMultiChildLayout(
                    delegate: SEditorLayoutDelegate(myModel),
                    children: myModel.allItemsList(), // draws e.g. rectangle
                  ));
                },
               ....
            ),
            VerticalDivider(),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor( ... ),
              child: PropertyInspector())
  ])
```

As I move the `widget` inside a `MultiChildLayoutDelegate` around, which draws a rectangle, using the mouse, the rectangle draws across the left column over the right column.

Inside the `performLayout()` method of `MultiChildLayoutDelegate`, I perform

```
positionChild(n, Offset(p.x, p.y));
layoutChild(n, BoxConstraints.expand(width: p.width, height: p.height));
```

Obviously, this makes the rectangle drawing widget overlap the right column.

**How do I clip the `widget` in the left column to not overlap the right column?**

[image]

Comment: some reproducible code sample would be nice

Comment: Close? Hey, folks, what is bad about this post?

Comment: A `ClipRect`, perhaps?

Comment: @Abion47 Thank you! Perfect hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expected `Row` to restrict the drawing of its several children to their respective screen areas. In fact, it does not.

Therefore one needs to wrap the drawing area within a [ClipRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html), to make the painting of each client get clipped to its screen area.

Code:

```
ClipRect(
  child: Center(
    child: CustomMultiChildLayout(
     delegate: SEditorLayoutDelegate(myModel),
     children: myModel.allItemsList(),
     )
   )
);
```

Result:

[image]